# Can copula+adjective be transitive or intransitive?

Tags: grammar, linguistics, transitivity

The beginning of the article [What is consciousness, and could machines have it?](http://science.sciencemag.org/content/358/6362/486) (full text PDF is a google search away) contains the following:

> The word “consciousness,” like many prescientific terms, is used in
>   widely different senses. In a medical context, it is often used in
>   an intransitive sense (as in, “the patient was no longer
>   conscious”) [...]
>
> [...]
>
> This corresponds to the transitive meaning of consciousness (as in
>   “The driver is conscious of the light”).

Is this the correct distinction to draw between these two occurrences of the word "conscious"? Is there a more precise way to draw this distinction, since transitivity is usually a property of verbs, and there's (yet) no verb  with a root "conscious", as far as I can tell.

Comment: 'Transitivity' / 'transitive' have various definitions. Even in linguistics, many hold with the term 'transitive prepositions'. And [Collins](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/transitive) sense (2) gets close to  the sense used here: << 2. (Grammar) _transitive_ denoting an adjective, such as fond, or a noun, such as husband, that requires [here, allows] a noun phrase [/ prepositional phrase] [in standard use] and cannot be used without some implicit or explicit reference to such a noun phrase >>.

Comment: If the driver was _not_ conscious of the light - would that be intransitive ?

Comment: Copular clauses are always intransitive. The adjective "conscious" is predicative complement of "be". The PP "of the light" is complement of "conscious". Your second example is thus not a transitive clause.

Comment: That's one parse that's available. Another parse that's available is to consider _conscious of_ as a transitive predicate, essentially as if it were inflected. Speakers choose between the parses, as they like, and quite often speaker and listener would parse differently, though in most cases it makes no difference.

Comment: I know what you mean. But I sense that the OP is seeking a clarification of 'transitivity'. I would be reluctant to suggest that they think of "conscious of" as a constituent, since it clearly isn't -- syntactically any following NP would be complement of the prep "of", not of "conscious of".

Comment: Incidentally -- there are, I believe, only four adjectives that license NP complements: "worth", "like", "unlike" and "due", and hence are called 'transitive adjectives'.

Comment: Thanks for these comments, they helped. If any one wants to write it into an answer, that might help.

I didn't understand the point about the two available parses. Is there some parse tree where "conscious of" captured in a subtree, thereby suggesting it's a constituent?